# Datos que se pierden de la BBDD Oracle

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

tenemos un problema con una aplicación de la que llevamos el mantenimiento y nos hemos hemos encontrado con el siguiente problema.
Resulta que ingresamos unos valores en una tabla, hasta ahí bien, los vemos en pantalla y sin problema. Una vez sales de la aplicación y vuelves a entrar o simplemente refrescas la pantalla los datos han desaparecido de la tabla. Este caso es aleatorio, no sucede siempre.
Las consultas las hacemos con Hibernate.
¿A alguien le ha pasado alguna vez?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hay una posibilidad de que pase eso. Cuando no se hace commit a la transacción, los registros permanecen visibles durante la session y si no se "comitean" estos se pierden con la session.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Blasito. Creo que ya se más o menos de donde puede venir ahora que lo has dicho, muchas gracias por orientarme.